# Change color of some items in lstlisting

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I have to include code of subroutines in my document. To do that, I used `lstlisting`. I successfully include subroutines, but I want to make small change.

In visual studio, the function inputs are highlighted as gray. For example,

```
\begin{lstlisting}
double foo(double a){
    return a * a;
}
\end{lstlisting}
```

[image]}

In here, I want to highlight `a` as gray color. I can do this by adding

```
\lstset{
    OTHEROPTIONS,
    keywords=[2]{a},
    keywordstyle=[2]\color{gray},
}
```

[image]

However, if I set like this, it will affect the whole listings even the listings `a` is not an input. So, I want to do like following

```
\lstset{
    OTHEROPTIONS,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    keywordstyle=[2]\color{gray},
}
\begin{lstlisting}
// This Code will have black `a`
void main(){
    double b = foo(a);
}
\end{lstlisting}
\begin{lstlisting}[keyword=0.5]
double foo(double a){
    return a * a;
}
\end{lstlisting}
```

[image]
[image]

is there any possible way?

---

Complete code for first figure.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{paper}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\definecolor{mygreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{mygray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mymauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\lstset{
    tabsize=4,    
%   rulecolor=,
    language={C++},
        captionpos = t,
        basicstyle = \footnotesize\ttfamily,
        frame=lines,
        numbersep=5pt,
        numbers=left,
        numberstyle=\tiny,
        backgroundcolor=\color{white},
        aboveskip={1.5\baselineskip},
        columns=fixed,
        extendedchars=false,
        breaklines=true,
%        prebreak = \raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\hookleftarrow}},
        frame=single,
        showtabs=false,
        showspaces=false,
        showstringspaces=false,
        keywordstyle=\color[rgb]{0,0,1},
        keywordstyle=[2]\color{gray},
        commentstyle=\color{mygreen},
        stringstyle=\color{red},
        numberstyle=\color[rgb]{0.205, 0.142, 0.73},
}




% DOCUMENT STARTS
% HERE                                                                                                              
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[title=main.cpp]
// This code will have black `a`
void main(){
    double a = 0.5;
    cout << foo(a) << endl;
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you add a complete MWE which begin with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`

Comment: I added complete code which will give you first figure.

Answer (score 8):

Why don't you use `escapechar` option, and then set color on every item that you want?
Really, I have no idea how to do that automatically.

add the following option to the `lsset`:

```
escapechar={|},
```

so you can use the code, below:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[title=main.cpp]
// This code will have black `a`
void main(){
    double |\color{gray}a| = 0.5;
    cout << foo(a) << endl;
}
\end{lstlisting}
```

the result is:
[image]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks!